# STL container template parameter containing certain object

Tags: c++, templates, stl, containers

I have a function `f`:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T<int> ints)
{ /* */ }
```

This function is supposed to take `std::vector<int>` or `std::initializer_list<int>` or any other STL container, but only, if it contains `int`.

I can live with it accepting other `class`es with `int` as a template parameter, but I don't want it to accept `std::vector<char>` or `std::vector<double>` or `std::list<double>` or something like this.

How can I realize this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *could* use a template template parameter:

```
template <template <typename...> typename T>
void f(const T<int>& ints)
{ /* */ }
```

But I would recommend using the `value_type` type member of containers instead. This will avoid matching other templates with `int` as the template parameter.

```
//using std::enable_if_t
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<typename T::value_type, int>::value> 
f(const T& ints)
{ /* */ }

//or static_assert
template <typename T>
void f(const T& ints) { 
    static_assert(std::is_same<typename T::value_type, int>::value,
                  "T must be a container of ints"); 
    //...
}
```

Comment: Is there some value to prefering one approach over the other (`std::enable_if_t` vs. `static_assert`)?

Comment: @hgiesel The `std::enable_if` approach allows you to have other overloads which can be chosen if that version is invalid, and also documents your type requirements in the declaration. The `static_assert` approach gives a better error message and doesn't muddy your declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Pedantically, that is a function template from which a function is instantiated.

One solution is to detect `value_type` which standard containers provide:

```
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<int, typename T::value_type>::value>::type
void f(T const& ints);
```

That will not work with built-in arrays though, as they do not have embedded `value_type`. For built-in arrays you can add an overload:

```
template<size_t N>
void f(int const(&ints)[N]);
```